# Customizing JSON output CakePHP

Tags: json, cakephp, json-view

```
    $user = $this->User->find( 'all' );
    $this->set( 'users', $user );
```

I have this code in my controller.

In my view I have this.

```
echo json_encode( compact( 'users' ) );
```

It outputs json like this

```
    {
    "users": [{
        "User": {
            "user_id": "2",
            "email": "email@test.com",
            "name": "Blah"
        }]
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to format this to remove the entire array wrapped in "users", and also remove every object being a member of "User".

This makes it harder to use on the front end.  I'd like it to look like this.

```
[{
    "user_id": "2",
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "name": "Blah"
}]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you mean by "***remove the entire array wrapped in "users"***" and "***remove every object being a member of "User"***", but according to your desired output format example, you'll need to extract and pass the exact data that you want to be encoded to `json_encode`, instead of passing everything using `compact`.

Extracting could be done with the [`Set`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/view/640/Set) or the [`Hash`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) class (depending on your Cake version)

Assuming your model returns the data in the default CakePHP format, this for example:

```
json_encode(Set::extract('/User/.', $users));
```

should give you a structure like this:

```
[{
    "user_id": "2",
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "name": "Blah"
}]
```

and with multiple users it should look like this

```
[{
    "user_id": "1",
    "email": "foo@test.com",
    "name": "Bar"
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "name": "Blah"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$users= (Set::extract('/User/.', $users));
pr($users);
```

It will remove `Model` from result Array and then `json_encode` or whatever further usage.

More library functions [Set class Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html) and [Hash class Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html)